# Newbie Controller Error with Angular/ionic

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework, parameters, get

I have a date selector linked to a data feed which works fine with "date" but doesn't recognise "date2" - it appends an "undefined" to my external get URL. It's a problem with my controller but I'm new so I was hoping someone could walk me through the error! I don't know how to reference the "date2" as a stateparam...

Code is as follows:

```
    .controller("DateCtrl", function ($scope, $stateParams, dateService) {
    $scope.events = dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date).then(function (events) {
$scope.events = events;
console.log("Date Controller1 says: Hello World - I also work");

 });
```

factory....

```
 .factory('dateService', function ($http) {
var events = [];

return {
    getEvents: function (date, date2) {
        var params = {
            date:date,
            date2:date2
        }


        return $http.get('url&' + params.date + "-" + params.date2).then(function (response) {
            events = response.data.events;
            return response.data.events;
        });
    },
```

Stackoverflow wont let me post my html so i'll have describe it. Which is really annoying. It is two input fields with ng-models for date and date2

EDIT:

State

```
    .state('date', {
url: "/date/:date/:date2",
templateUrl: "templates/Date.html",
controller: "DateCtrl"
```

})

Comment: You are only passing one value to the factory `dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date)` when it expects 2 => `getEvents: function (date, date2)` therefore `date2` will always be `undefined` in the factory.

Comment: I know...but no matter what i've tried I can't add the second date2 to the controller. Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: can you show what `$stateParams` looks like

Comment: forgot that! Added to question...

Comment: So pass data like so: `dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date, $stateParams.date2)`

Comment: I don't believe it. It works. I'm sure I tried that....I've spent weeks on this and it was that obvious....Thank you!!  You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing just one value to your factory

```
dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date)
```

just add a second value like so and that should work:

```
dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date, $stateParams.date2)
```

hope it helps.